# I am getting an error because I may not writing the correct file path

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

[image]

You can see file location here and error displayed below.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your path is wrong.

Try ../../useTransactions if you are trying to go back two folders.

or just ./ if in the same folder.

if its under src it would be 4 folders back

src/comp/Main/Form/Details

../ Goes to Form
../../ Goes to Main
../../../ Goes to comp
../../../../ Goes to src

Comment: Did not work can using ../../useTransactions

Comment: Are you trying to go two level back? each ../ will go one level back ./ just means same directory please post folder structure

Comment: @mohanKunwar Do you know what `../` means…? How many directories is `useTransactions` up? Looks like it’s in …`/src`; how many directories is that away from …`/src/comp/Main/Form/Details`? Two? Or four?

Comment: It's under src so it's two

Comment: If its under src it would be 4 ../../../../